# How can I redirect all traffic from one domain to another with an .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Say I have a subdomain `xxx.yyy.com` running Apache. The files are stored in `/home/someone/public_html/xxx`.

What I want to do is redirect all requests to a domain name `zzz.com` which is using the same location for its files. (In other words, `xxx.yyy.com` and `zzz.com` are aliases for each other)

I just want people accessing `zzz.com`, so if someone goes to `xxx.yyy.com` they should be redirected to `zzz.com`.

Can this easily be done with a rewrite rule in an .htaccess file?

Comment: CNAME alias in DNS IIRC.

Comment: How would that work? I have the capability to edit DNS zone configuration files.

Comment: I think I have it wrong (well partially), and you want a rewrite rule too (as in the answer given below). Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.yyy\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://zzz.com/$1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```

Comment: If this does not work at first, try changing the apache.conf (on linux: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ) setting `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` inside the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` configuration.  Then restart apache ( on linux: /etc/init.d/httpd restart )