# How to redirect user from one domain to another domain to a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, cname

I have a domain called `olddomain.com`. Now I want to point the DNS entry to  `newdomain.com`. Can I then use a .htaccess which determines if the user comes from `olddomain.com` and redirects to `newdomain.com/path/welcomepage.html`?

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/94421/redirecting-based-on-url-via-htaccess/94449#94449) and created something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.olddomain.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/welcomepage.html$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Would this work (together with pointing the A-record or CName-record on `newdomain.com`)?

The redirect should be permanent. So should I use R=permanent,QSA,L like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505690/how-can-i-redirect-all-traffic-from-one-domain-to-another-with-an-htaccess-file/2505719#2505719)?

Edit:

Now I tried the lines from Seybsen together with the following CName record:

Typ:
CName record
Name:
www.olddomain.com.
TTL:
3600
Cname: newdomain.com.

But the result is (with and without the redirect) that only a advertisement from the provider of newdomain.com is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/path/welcomepage.html [R=301,L]
```

means: when someone gets to your page via olddomain.com or www.olddomain.com he will be redirected to the newdomain's welcomepage.

**EDIT:**

If you have the possibility to set an A-Record for www.olddomain.com and olddomain.com I would set them both to newdomain's server IP.

A CNAME for the domain olddomain.com would be [against DNS RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655235/is-root-domain-cname-to-other-domain-allowed-by-dns-rfc) so not advisable; you can only set it for www.olddomain.com what will require a redirect (for example with a [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847814/301-redirect-where-2-domains-point-to-same-ip/7848399#7848399)) from olddomain.com to www.olddomain.com which then points through CNAME to www.newdomain.com
I'm assuming here that www.olddomain.com and olddomain.com should both show the welcomepage of newdomain.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you also help me with the Cname record? Do I have to contact the provider or I'm doing something wrong? See my edited question.

Comment: Try contacting the provider of newdomain. Your CNAME seems to be correct.

Comment: I contacted the provider from www.oldomain.com and www.newdomain.com. At both I had to set up a redirect (which only is available from the domain provider). I never could test it because I had problems and in the end the domain was canceled....